# regular expression to parse html title tag

Tags: regex, powershell, html-parsing

I need to parse a lot of html files in order to know which ones contain specific text within title tag.

Let's suppose that titles are

```
file1.htm
<title>100 text other text</title>
file2.htm
<title>text 100 text other text</title>
file3.htm
<title>text 1000 text other text</title>
file4.htm
<title>text one hundred text other text</title>
```

Following my example I need to find files name that contain 100 or one hundred, that is files 1,2 and 4.

My problem is that I don't know how to write regular expression

```
gci "c:\my_folder" | ? {$_.extension -eq ".htm"} | 
select-string -pattern '<title>*100*</title>' |
Select-Object -Unique Path
```

Please note, if this may be important for regexp, that title tag is not at the beginning of a row but in the middle.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: normally, using regex to parse HTML is bad. just FYI.

Comment: Obligatory warning about parsing HTML using regular expressions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: To expand a little on this point: the contents of the `title` element might extend over multiple lines; they might contain other HTML markup. HTML markup in general is unsuited to regular-expression processing because of its nested structure. Perhaps in this case you know exactly how your input files were made, and you know that the title is always on a single line and never contains anything difficult. **IF** that is so, then regular expressions may not be a crazy approach. Otherwise, you really ought to use a proper parser.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I've read the link but if it's bad and I can't parse them do I have some alternative? edit. Now I read your last reply.

Comment: I don't know anything about PowerShell, but you should try replacing `*` with `.*` in the pattern. `.` matches any character. `*` means "any number of things matching the thing I just said". So `.*` means "any number of arbitrary characters". But, I repeat, please consider carefully whether regular expressions are really an appropriate tool for this job.

Comment: Thanks again Gareth for your detailed answers. I'll google for some alternative if powershell is not the right tool for this job.

Comment: Regexes are _fun!_ But I would strongly recommend spending an hour or two studying the basics. There is an excellent online tutorial at: [www.regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/). The time you spend there will pay for itself many times over. Happy regexing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it.

```
^.*<title>(.*(100|one\shundred)[^0].*)?</title>.*$
```

Comment: May I ask you what [^0] does it mean?

Comment: Don't allow 1000, which 100+0

Comment: @nick rulez, like the above comment says, this will stop it matching 1000 says do not allow 0 as the next character.

Comment: Ah, ok. Now I've understood. Thanks again for your kindness. :)

Comment: This solution (`^.*<title>(.*(100|one\shundred)[^0].*)?</title>.*$`) is overusing the greedy-dot-star! (It is doing a _LOT_ of unnecessary work, especially when testing long files which don't match.) And there is no need to match anything before or after the TITLE element. A better (and much faster) expression would be: `<title>[^<]*?\b(100|one\s+hundred)\b[^<]*</title>`.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
<title>(.*[^[:alnum:]])?(100|one hundred)([^[:alnum:]].*)?</title>
```

for the pattern to match. pattern syntax is PCRE (like in perl), it can be reformulated if necessary.

best regards,

carsten

ps:
beware of the pitfalls - all the recommendations and warnings from the comments do hold; still, in your case, the regex approach seems viable (mainly because you're investigating the 'title' tag's content, there should only be a single one per file and spreading it across multiple lines would be plain silly imho).

Comment: Thanks collapsar. Even your solution seems perfect. I gave you an upvote too but I've accept jimplode's answer because he replied first. Thanks again. You're genious. I'm afraid I'll never learn these regexps. :(

Comment: thanks. be warned however that the solution you've accepted would match '<title>one hundredth</title>' too, which might not be what you want. greetz, carsten

Comment: Thanks for the warning. As you have seen I'm totally newbie with regexp, so I'm not able to catch those little particulars. :) I will not have "hundredth" problem cause my native language is italian. I've put the problem in english terms in order to be understood from everybody. I needed to parse italian strings ;) Thanks again.